# No coordinates when searching by geocode with R twitteR-package

Tags: r, twitter

```
searchTwitter('patriots', geocode='42.375,-71.1061111,10mi')
```

This query returns a list of tweets. However, most of these tweets have no location:

```
retweeted    longitude    latitude
1      FALSE         <NA>        <NA>
2      FALSE         <NA>        <NA>
3      FALSE         <NA>        <NA>
...
```

Why is that? How did twitter know that these tweets are within the range of the search query? Is there a way to get an estimate of the coordinates of these tweets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets#api-param-search_geocode) says

> The location is preferentially taking from the Geotagging API, **but will fall back to their Twitter profile.**

You should find that if you check the user of each tweet they have set their profile location and it falls within `10` miles of `42.375,-71.1061111'`.